# How can I generate or import multiple json files in one, with webpack?

Tags: json, webpack

I have multiple json files, and want to transform they to one simple json file and use `json-loader` to require it, like this:

`import dictionary from './distFile.json';`

Example:
**file1.json**
`{a:"b"}`
**file2.json**
{b:"a"}
**distFile.json** *should be:*
`{a:"b",b:"a"}`

How can I do that?

Or there is anyway to do something like that:
`import dictionary from ['./file1.json','./file2.json'];` ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make a third file that you require both files in.

**combined.js**

```
import file1 from './file1.json';
import file2 from './file2.json';
export default { ...file1, ...file2 };
```

Then just import that file:

```
import combinedJson from './combined.js'
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (4:17)  
  
  2 | import file1 from './file1.json';  
  3 | import file2 from './file2.json';    
> 4 | export default { ...file1, ...file2 };  
    |                  ^  
  5 |

Comment: Just added babel 'stage-2' preset and it works! thanks